# How to use Sweetalert in main.js Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, axios

I was learning Vue 3 and get some trouble to use SweetAlert2 in app.js.

everything is ok and worked when i use SweetAlert2 in component Vue but not work in app.js

my goal:
i want to show alert with confirm button when get error response Unauthenticated. from axios interceptors and redirect user to login page

app.js

```
import {createApp} from 'vue'
require('./bootstrap')
import App from './App.vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

// SweetAlert2
import VueSweetalert2 from 'vue-sweetalert2';
import 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css';

axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    return response
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error.response.data.message)
    if (error.response.data.message === 'Unauthenticated.') {
        swal({
            title: "Session Expired",
            text: "Your session has expired. Would you like to be redirected to the login page?",
            icon: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes",
            closeOnConfirm: false
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
                window.location.href = "/login"
            }
        });     
}
    return Promise.reject(error)
})

const app = createApp(App)
app.config.globalProperties.$axios = axios;
app.use(router)
app.use(VueSweetalert2)
app.use(store)
app.mount('#app')
```

it work when i change error response with this, (but not elegant like this for me)

```
...
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
        return response
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error.response.data.message)
        if (error.response.data.message === 'Unauthenticated.') {
            alert('Session Expired');
            window.location.href = "/login"
    }
        return Promise.reject(error)
    })
...
```

i think it would be good if using sweetalert,

thank youu...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

I faced the same problem when using Vue 3, and I wanted to use sweetalert2 in my `router/index.js` to add an alert when a user goes to an unauthorized route.

The same problem will appear if you want to use a sweetalert2 in `store/index.js` after calling an action fetching data from the backend.

To work around this problem, you must use the native package of [sweetalert2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sweetalert2), then you can use *swal* in any `.js` file.

By the way, I don't want to install any external package, so I found that when you are installing the [vue-sweetalert2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-sweetalert2), the native package will be installed also (because it is a dependency of *vue-sweetalert2*).

### Workaround

All you have to do is:

- Keep what you had done in `main.js` (to use sweetalert2 inside components).
- In any `.js` file where you want to use swal, add this `import Swal from 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2'`, and now you can access and use `Swal.fire({})`.

### Example

I will attach an example of what I want to do (in my case), and how I work around the problem:

#### My `main.js` file:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import store from './store';
import router from './router';
import VueSweetalert2 from 'vue-sweetalert2';
import 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css';

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(store);
app.use(router);
app.use(VueSweetalert2);

app.mount('#app');
```

#### My `router/index.js`

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2';
import store from '../store/index';

const router = createRouter({
  routes: [
    // ...
  ],
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta['requiresAuth']) && store.state.auth.isAuthenticated === false) {
    Swal.fire({
      toast: true,
      position: 'bottom-end',
      showConfirmButton: false,
      timer: 3000,
      timerProgressBar: true,

      icon: 'error',
      title: 'Permission denied',
      text: 'You are not authenticated to access this page.'
    });

    next({
      name: 'login',
      params: { nextUrl: to.fullPath }
    });
  }

  next();
});

export default router;
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you need to try withoud condition first,
try only sweet alert without :

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    return response
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error.response.data.message)
    if (error.response.data.message === 'Unauthenticated.') {
        swal({
            title: "Session Expired",
            text: "Your session has expired. Would you like to be redirected to the login page?",
            icon: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes",
            closeOnConfirm: false
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
                window.location.href = "/login"
            }
        });     
}
    return Promise.reject(error)
})
```

u can try

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-sweetalert2